# Python code to display default page name for url

Tags: url, default

is there a way in python to display what the default initial page is for www.xyz.com when there isn't an index.html, default.html page?

For example I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to do the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.example.com/index.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
print(bsObj.h1)
```

But index.html and default.html do not exist.

How do I find out what the default page is when I go to www.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `urlopen("http://www.example.com/")`, which will open the default page served by the webserver.

Comment: Thanks James, I stummbled upon that myself. I appreciate your help :-)